# Can I setup a VPN at home or on a VPS and connect to the Internet through it?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, ip

My employer in the US has asked me to obtain a static IP address to enable him lock down his servers to the general public, allowing just our IP addresses. The cost of obtaining an IP address here is alarming (over $600 USD). He's suggested that I setup a VPN or some other system to mask my public IP with a static one.

I own quite a few devices that I connect to the internet. Can I setup a VPN at home or on a rented server and connect to the internet using the VPN network? Will doing this give me a permanent IP address? What options do I have?

Comment: Where do you live, n3rve? 600 bucks for an IP address???

Comment: The only guarantee way you will have a static ip address that will not be changed is if you setup your own vpn server, on your own server or VPS, and pay for said static ip address.  Otherwise there is a significant hcance that any ip address you are normally assigned, when you connect to a paid VPN service, could be changed.  Unless you pay for a static address for that rented server there is no guarantee the address for said rented server wouldn't change.

Comment: Honestly, your employer should just provide the VPN access to whatever you need to access internally.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae In Nigeria. The $600 USD isn't just for the IP address, they want me to stack up my subscription for over a year which I currently pay at $50 USD per month. They say it's a company policy. This is my ISP's website: Smile Communications, Nigeria - http://smile.com.ng/

Comment: @Ramhound, that's helpful information, thank you. I can rent an EC2 instance from Amazon Web Services and set an elastic (static) IP address so it's permanent. I will look up VPN solutions that can be installed unto a Linux VPS. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JoshR This also seems like a good suggestion, however I would be the one to setup such a network and provide them with access. Can you point me towards any helpful resources to aid my understanding of what you're proposing and possibly get this rolling?

Comment: @n3rve - How you implement your solution is up to you.  Please don't ask for service or product recommendations they won't be given.  You currently have an excellent answer and addresses all your points.

Comment: Use OpenVPN, it is a bit tricky to setup because of SSL certificates, but thereare good guides everywhere, and it is the safest and most complete.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Thanks for the suggestion. I've found a guide for OpenVPN and I'm in the process of setting it up.

Comment: Try this service https://vpn4.one/. It does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a VPN server at home,but then all your connections (to your US employer or everywhere else, for this matter) will appear to come from your home IP address. If you have not paid extra money for your connection, chances are you do **not** have a static IP address, so that your connections will appear to be coming from several distinct IPs, and you will **not** have solved your problem.

You can however rent cheap VPSes everywhere in the world, including and especially in the US. The cheap ones are about 3 US dollars per month, and for that amount of money I have one with unmetered traffic (on two different providers, actually).

The VPS will necessarily come with a static IP, otherwise you would be unable to connect to it from a remote client.  You can then setup a VPN server on the US VPS, and then connect from it to your employer with a static IP. Connecting to the VPN server from any pc in your home LAN will allow to navigate with the VPS public IP,which is US-based, which entails some frills, Pandora, Vudu, Netflix and the like.

In my opinion this is by far your best option.

Edit:

My experience flatly contradicts Ramhound's, but even assuming you are right, you can do the following: get a third-level noip domain (it is free), set it up on your VPS, and give your provider **not** your IP address, but your domain name, which will always resolve correctly to your IP even if it changes.  It is free, and it solves your problem even in the **very unlikely** case that what Ramhound suggests will take place.

Comment: In my experience you connect to a dynamic url that the VPS provider give you.  It does not necessarily guarantee that address or the server your account exists on, won't be changed in the future.

Comment: @Ramhound Then you have been very unlucky in your choice of provider. I must have tried something like thirty providers, and not one, ever, changed my IP. But **even** if you are right, there is a solution...pls read my Edit.

Comment: MariusMatutiae, Your post has been very helpful. My experiences also contradict @Ramhound's as I maintain 3 virtual private servers and the assigned IP addresses haven't changed in 3 years despite re-installations and restarts. I will look up some solutions that I can setup on a VM. You all have been very helpful. Thanks!